# Is it unsafe to use Flask's route converters?

Tags: python, http, flask

I have a set of static data files on my server, which are named something like;

- file1.dat
- file2.dat
- file3.dat
- ...

I'm trying to serve these via an endpoint in my Flask app. Right now, I'm doing the following;

```
STATIC_DIRECTORY = Path("static/directory/location/on/my/server")
@app.route("/fetch_data/<file_number>", methods=["GET"])
def fetch_data(file_number: int) -> str:
    file_loc = STATIC_DIRECTORY / f"file{file_number}.dat"
    return file_loc.read_text()
```

Is it safe for me to use `file_number` in this way, or will it expose me to attacks similar to SQL injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think having the type annotation `: int` on the function has any effect.

```
@app.route("/fetch_data/<int:file_number>", methods=["GET"])
```

would enable the `int` converter ... but if you want to be extra safe, instead of

```
f"file{file_number}.dat"
```

you can do

```
f"file{int(file_number)}.dat"
```

Comment: oh fantastic, I didn't realise that Flask had typing built in to the converters like that. Thanks so much!